# How can I run multiple USB webcams on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, video, webcam

I wanted to build a system that can take live video data from four different webcams to run object detection over, but each time I try running a second webcam, the first shuts down.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with webcams that are 640x480 pixels via mmp(yuyv) at 30FPS and for some reason when I run ls/dev/video each camera registers as two (what I mean is when I plug in one camera and run 'ls/dev/video' I get 'video0' and 'video1').

When I plug in the second camera, I get a "VIDIOC_DQBUF error 19, No such device' error before the usb process dies.

Could someone help me fix this please?

Thank you!